# Proof: Well defined multiplication in groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Can anyone please show me how to prove this?

Define for sH ∈ G/H and tH ∈ G/H the
multiplication:

(sH)(tH) = (st)H

Show that this is well-defined.

How do I prove this? Also, I'm unsure of what I have to show as a part of this proof as I don't really understand what is meant by "**well-defined**" in this context? Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it?

Answer (score 1):

"Well defined" means that the result of the multiplication doesn't depend on how you represent the coset. That is, suppose that $s_1H=s_2H$ are two ways to represent the same coset. In order for the operation to be well defined, it must be true that $$(s_1H)(tH)=(s_2H)(tH)$$ for any other coset $tH$ (if $x=y$, then $xz=yz$). So you need to show that 
$$
s_1H=s_2H\qquad\implies\qquad s_1tH=s_2tH
$$

Comment: Is this proof alright: Let $aH=kH$ Then $(aH)(bH)=$(ab)(H)$ => (kH)(bH)=(kH)(Hb)=(Hk)(Hb)=(HH)(kb)=H(kb)=(kb)H

Comment: Would this(^) work? I'm assuming associativity and definition of a normal subgroup